# Altium 18 Place 3D bodyl dialog box missing

Tags: altium, 3d

I'm trying to import a .step model into my footprint. I just upgraded to Altium 18 last night, and for some reason when I either click the icon to place 3D Body or go to the Place->3D Body menu, it doesn't open the dialog box. Instead, my crosshairs turn green and it wants me to define some kind of region. How do I get the dialog box to appear? It's not opening in the background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the properties window is open, In altium 18 a lot of functions are incorporated into the "properties window" including this one.

[image: Properties window]

There you should be able to find your options to place an external .step file, click the generic button under 3D model type and you can browse for an embed model path.[image: Generic model]

Comment: Unfortunately, Altium messed this up - you can't reach the 'Properties' panel easily, first you have to click on the schematics, place a rectangle or a single point there, and only then you are able to select anything.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean If I use Place > 3d body > TAB-Key then you will get the pause button in the center of your screen, and you are free to access any panel, properties menu or whatever you want to do without having to click on schematics or place anything.

Comment: Stuff like this (along with the ugly black color scheme) is why we're still using 17.

Comment: @RemcoVink Oh, that's a pause icon. I was still under the impression they removed the whole Tab-dialog features completely and replaced the shortcut by something else...

Comment: @RemcoVink thanks, I found that as soon as I clicked on the "Place 3D Model" button, my properties menu disappeared. It took me a while to find that it had collapsed the menu and turned it into a tiny button on the top right corner of the screen.